# How to update core-js to core-js@3 dependency?

Tags: react-native, npm-install

While I was trying to install and setup react native, the precaution observed about the core-js version as update your core-js@... to core-js@3 But don't know how to update my core-js.

```
$ sudo react-native init AwesomeProject121
Password:
This will walk you through creating a new React Native project in /Users/amarnr1989/AwesomeProject121
Using yarn v1.13.0
Installing react-native...
yarn add v1.13.0
info No lockfile found.
[1/4]   Resolving packages...
warning react-native > create-react-class > fbjs > core-js@1.2.7: core-js@<2.6.5 is no longer maintained. Please, upgrade to core-js@3 or at least to actual version of core-js@2.
[2/4]   Fetching packages...
[----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------] 0/601internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:584
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module '/Users/amarnr1989/AwesomeProject121/node_modules/react-native/package.json'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:582:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:508:25)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:637:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:22:18)
    at checkNodeVersion (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/react-native-cli/index.js:306:21)
    at run (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/react-native-cli/index.js:300:3)
    at createProject (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/react-native-cli/index.js:249:3)
    at init (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/react-native-cli/index.js:200:5)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/react-native-cli/index.js:153:7)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:701:30)
```

Please Suggest

Comment: You don't need to do anything with core-js, just follow React Native Get Started guide for "React Native CLI Quickstart".

Comment: Also please DONT use sudo with npm packages.

Comment: `npm i --save-dev core-js@3 @babel/runtime-corejs3`

Answer (score 90, accepted):

You update core-js with the following command:

```
npm install --save core-js@^3
```

If you read the [React Docs](https://reactjs.org/blog/2017/09/25/react-v15.6.2.html) you will find that the command is derived from when you need to upgrade React itself.

Comment: he dosn't help me!

Comment: You need to elaborate on how it doesn't help.

Comment: Although I did everything, he continues to give me this message

Comment: What is the equivalent to this in yarn?

Comment: @Slowwie: the equivalent would be: `yarn add core-js@^3`

Answer (score 12):

For npm

```
 npm install --save core-js@^3
```

for yarn

```
yarn add core-js@^3
```

Answer (score 6):

For ng9 upgraders:

`npm i -g core-js@^3`

..then:

`npm cache clean -f`

..followed by:

`npm i`

Answer (score 3):

How about reinstalling the node module? Go to `the root directory` of the project and remove the current `node modules` and install again.

These are the commands : `rm -rf node_modules npm install`

OR

`npm uninstall -g react-native-cli` and

```
npm install -g react-native-cli
```

Comment: Try loading without using sudo

Comment: This helped a bit

Answer (score 3):

With this

```
npm install --save core-js@^3
```

you now get the error

```
"core-js@<3 is no longer maintained and not recommended for usage due to the number of
issues. Please, upgrade your dependencies to the actual version of core-js@3"
```

so you might want to instead try

```
npm install --save core-js@3
```

if you're reading this post June 9 2020.

Answer (score 0):

Install

```
npm i core-js
```

Modular standard library for JavaScript. Includes polyfills for ECMAScript up to 2019: promises, symbols, collections, iterators, typed arrays, many other features, ECMAScript proposals, some cross-platform WHATWG / W3C features and proposals like URL. You can load only required features or use it without global namespace pollution.

Read: https://www.npmjs.com/package/core-js

Comment: Is there a difference between deleting the node_modules files with the 'DELETE' key and deleting them using 'uninstall...'?