# Command `yarn add react-native --exact` failed

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, yarnpkg

I tryed to create new project but this happen , I update the core as they said here [How to update core-js to core-js@3 dependency?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55606841/how-to-update-core-js-to-core-js3-dependency)
 but also no thing help me
I use windows 10, what should I do ?

```
c:\Users\alothman\Desktop>npx react-native init travelApp
This will walk you through creating a new React Native project in c:\Users\alothman\Desktop\travelApp
Using yarn v1.21.1
Installing react-native...
yarn add v1.21.1
info No lockfile found.
[1/4] Resolving packages...
warning react-native > fbjs > core-js@2.6.11: core-js@<3 is no longer maintained and not recommended for usage due to the number of issues. Please, upgrade your dependencies to the actual version of core-js@3.
warning react-native > create-react-class > fbjs > core-js@1.2.7: core-js@<3 is no longer maintained and not recommended for usage due to the number of issues. Please, upgrade your dependencies to the actual version of core-js@3.
warning react-native > fbjs-scripts > core-js@2.6.11: core-js@<3 is no longer maintained and not recommended for usage due to the number of issues. Please, upgrade your dependencies to the actual version of core-js@3.
warning react-native > metro-babel-register > core-js@2.6.11: core-js@<3 is no longer maintained and not recommended for usage due to the number of issues. Please, upgrade your dependencies to the actual version of core-js@3.
[2/4] Fetching packages...
error An unexpected error occurred: "C:\\Users\\alothman\\AppData\\Local\\Yarn\\Cache\\v6\\npm-@babel-runtime-7.7.7-194769ca8d6d7790ec23605af9ee3e42a0aa79cf-integrity\\node_modules\\@babel\\runtime\\.yarn-metadata.json: Unexpected token \u0000 in JSON at position 0".
info If you think this is a bug, please open a bug report with the information provided in "c:\\Users\\alothman\\Desktop\\travelApp\\yarn-error.log".
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/add for documentation about this command.
{ Error: Command failed: yarn add react-native --exact
    at checkExecSyncError (child_process.js:629:11)
    at execSync (child_process.js:666:13)
    at run (C:\Users\alothman\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\react-native-cli\index.js:294:5)
    at createProject (C:\Users\alothman\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\react-native-cli\index.js:249:3)
    at init (C:\Users\alothman\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\react-native-cli\index.js:200:5)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\alothman\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\react-native-cli\index.js:153:7)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:778:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:789:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:593:12)
  status: 1,
  signal: null,
  output: [ null, null, null ],
  pid: 5380,
  stdout: null,
  stderr: null }
Command `yarn add react-native --exact` failed.
```

Comment: It seems that yarn found NUL characters (bye 0x00) in `.yarn-metadata.json`. Did you edit this using Notepad or another Windows editor? If so, it probably saved it as Unicode rather than plain ASCII (sometimes called ANSI)

Comment: No ,I do not change any thing

Answer (score 12):

I think you might be getting this errors because you have previously installed **react-native-cli** globally. So, first remove **react-native-cli** using following command:

```
npm uninstall -g react-native-cli
```

Now try creating project:

```
npx react-native init travelApp
```

Comment: This solved the the issue of node engine outdated as well. Thanks for the useful information

Answer (score 5):

```
npm config set registry "https://registry.npmjs.org"
```

This worked for me!

Comment: I dont know how or why this solved my problem. I just saw it in this [issue](https://github.com/yarnpkg/yarn/issues/3227)

Answer (score 2):

Check that you are using the correct node version ( >= 12.13.0 ):

`node --version`

If you are not using the correct version, install the latest using nvm and switch to that version.

https://heynode.com/tutorial/install-nodejs-locally-nvm/

Answer (score 1):

For me, the issue was using an older version of node. I upgraded to node v12, then tried installing again, and it worked.

`nvm install 12`

`nvm use 12`

and then

`react-native init Project`

Comment: Thank you. It worked for me!

Answer (score 1):

You can use this command to resolve this issue

```
npx react-native@latest init YourProjectName
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to upgrade the node version.

You can install >10.0 node.

Answer (score 0):

If you have already installed Node on your system, make sure it is Node 14 or newer.

Comment: This doesn't seem different from the existing answers. You could consider adding additional details as to why this solves the issue.